# Unnecessary rendering issue if we use onChange or PreferenceKey modifier in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In this down code I am using Binding in a custom View called TextView, which will not use this Binding in it's body, It will just sitting there.

The things get weird when we use onChange or PreferenceKey in our project that makes changing behavior of View for unused Binding in body. So here is what happens if we don't use onChange or PreferenceKey in our project and we update that unused Binding in our project that doesn't make the view get rendered and even we don't need to defined and conform to Equitable function to help SwiftUI to understand that it is the same View. It will work even without defining Equitable function or conforming to Equitable protocol. But when we use onChange or PreferenceKey on that unused Binding and even if we use and define Equitable and Equitable function for the View it will render it any way! Even it is not necessary so I don't know how can I solve this issue!?

```
    struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var string: String = "Hello" {

        didSet {

            print(string)

        }

    }


    var body: some View {

        EquatableView(content: TextView(string: $string))

        Button("update") { string += " updated!" }
          //.onChange(of: string) { newValue in  }  // <<: Here!!!

    }

}

struct TextView: View, Equatable {

    @Binding var string: String

    let value: String = "123"

    var body: some View {

        print("rendering TextView!", "- - - - - - ")

        return Text(value)

    }

    static func == (lhs: TextView, rhs: TextView) -> Bool {

        print("Equatable function used!")

        return lhs.value == rhs.value

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add `.onChange(of: string) { ... }` you are referencing `string` in `body` of `ContentView`, and if the value changes, body of ContentView will be executed - and thus `body` of `TextView`, too.

In your setup without  `.onChange` you are not referencing the value of `string` in the body of ContentView and changes to the value do not cause ContentView to be redrawn. And with- or without EquatableView, `body` of `TextView` should not be called when clicking the button.

In your pseudo code, I think, you do not need EquatableView - because there's nothing which could be optimised, and SwiftUI's default behaviour works well.

So far, it works as expected.

Now your question boils down to: how can I avoid to redraw a child view if the super view changes? (read: how to not execute `body` of a child view, if `body` of the super view will be executed)

Well, I think, SwiftUI can do optimisations - but I don't believe it can generally omit re-drawing a child view, when the super view changes and has been redrawn.

And now, when I think about it, you may use "ContentView" as the argument to EquatableView. Since, ContenView (presumably) does not depend on `string`.